# how to separate string with special character in Java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to separate string with special characters, but I am ending up with printing special characters in output.

```
public class SpecialCharacter {
final String GM= "GOOD MORNING";
        String s = "Juan";
        System.out.println("/\"" +s+ "/\""+GM);

    }

}
```

Actual Output : /"Juan/"GOOD MORNING

Accepted Output : "Juan" GOOD MORNING

Comment: "*string with special characters*" - what do you mean by this? --- Remove the `/` from the `String`s and your "*Actual Output*" will become the "*Accepted Output*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need backslash to escape:

```
System.out.println("\"" + s + "\" "  + GM);
```

**Output:** `"Juan" GOOD MORNING`

Comment: @Turing85 yeah, probably.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String GM= "GOOD MORNING";
String s = "Juan";
System.out.println("\"" + s + "\" "+ GM);
```

**Output:**

```
"Juan" GOOD MORNING
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You wanted to separate string by special characters. The scenario you presented merely prints two strings, with double quotes treated as special characters (separation of string is something like splitting a string, which is a different concept). So your question might have been like "how to escape double quotes while printing a string, or how to print a string with double quotes".
2. We use backslash "\" to escape special characters while scanning a string, your example is using a forward slash as well. This is the reason why forward slash is being printed as part of string.

To match your actual output with accepted output, you will need to omit the forward slash "/" from strings to make it work.